# Chrome won't work on my computer

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Some time ago I started noticing that Google Chrome would sometimes stop working on my computer, meaning any URL I typed would never open. I did not spen much of my time trying to figure it out. I just uninstalled Chrome and then reinstalled it back and it would resume working. This would happen very often, like once a week Chrome would throw that problem.

Then recently, uninstalling and reinstalling ceased working. Now Google Chrome is bugged even after uninstalling and reinstalling it back. All other browsers work like a charm (IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari). Worst of all, I cannot open any of the settings features on the browser to try to troubleshoot. The options menu item when clicked opens a new tab with the following URL: "chrome://settings/" and nothing happens. I get a white screen. The "Downloads" menu item in Chrome will open a new tab with "chrome://downloads/" written. Nothing happens.

I am on a Windows 7, 32 bits version.

Comment: Have you tried installing Canary?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any add-ons added to Chrome? If so, try disabling the add-ons and see if the issue still exists. Most of the issues I have encountered with Chrome have been due to the add-ons.

If that still does not work, put up a post here and someone should get back to you: [Chrome Support Forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/label?lid=27bfefca86e30fdb&hl=en)

Comment: Thank you, Mahendru. That did not solve the problem. Actually, none of Chrome's admin interfaces are working. When clicking any item, a new tab opens with things like this "chrome://settings/" on the URL field.

Answer (score 1):

Delete Chrome’s application folder first, *then* reinstall. When it installs, it may be simply overwriting existing files and some old files that are ignored may be causing problems. This is what happened a year or two ago that caused some similar problems to what you described.

The application folder might be in `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`, but assuming a default installation, it would likely be in

```
C:\Users\<Your Username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application
```

Of course, substitute in your username, then you should find one or more folders with numeric names; delete them all (or temporarily move them to some other location like the desktop). Reinstall and it *should* be okay.